# Laravel Eloquent indirect relation ship using hasMany

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My Question is essentially this, I have a issue with indirect reference to a model using a related model, like if a 'model A' has many 'model B' and 'model B' has many 'model C', so essentially that will be 'model A' has many 'model C' but I dont know how to relate them using hasMany.

Now my actual situation is I have a Shop with has many Product Categories,Each Product categories has many Products, So that Shop->ProductCategory is related using hasMany, as well as ProductCategory->Products using hasMany, I want to relate the Shop and Products without creating a new column in products table to store shop id.

Here is my models

```
/* Models */
// Shop.php
<?php
class Shop extends Eloquent {
  public function productCategories() {
    return $this->hasMany('ProductCategory');
  }
}
?>
//Product.php
<?php
class Product extends Eloquent {
  public function productCategory() {
    return $this->belongsTo('ProductCategory');
  }
}
?>
//ProductCategory.php
<?php
class ProductCategory extends Eloquent {
  public function shop() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Shop');
  }
  public function products() {
    return $this->hasMany('Product');
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

```
class Shop extends Eloquent {
    public function productCategories() {
        return $this->hasMany('ProductCategory');
    }
}

class ProductCategory extends Eloquent {
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('Product');
    }
}

$shop = Shop::with( array( 'productCategories', 'productcategory.products' ) )->get();
```

Comment: In this case I wont be able to get all products under shop, I would have to iterate over each category to get all products.

Instead of shop->products , i would have to write a loop to get all products right ?

Comment: Check the eager loading link given in the answer, there is an example for that, you can loop.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but it should be close...  Put this in your products model:

```
public static function getProductsByShop($shop_id)
{
    return DB::table('shops')
        ->where('shops.id','=',$shop_id)
        ->join('categories', 'categories.shop_id', '=', 'shops.id')
        ->join('products', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->select(DB::raw('products.*'))
        ->get();
}
```

And you can call it in your Controllers with `$products = Product::getProductsByShop(1);`

Then you can iterate over it with

```
foreach($products as $product)
{
    echo $product->name;
}
```

However, RCV's approach would be better on performance because you would only be querying what you need.  My approach will query everything and then pull out the rows with the shop you are looking for.  RCV's approach would just be an extra step when iterating...

```
foreach($shop->productCategories as $cat)
{
    foreach($cat->products as $product)
    {
        echo $product->name;
    }
}
```